# Hover is not working properly i can't change colors

Tags: css

I don't know why my CSS code is not working. I want to change a color of a link in a menu:

```css
.nav-item a {
  color: #357411 !important;
  font-family: 'Encode Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
  margin-bottom: 3px solid #ff7400;
  background: white
}

.nav-item a:visited {
  color: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
    <a class="nav-link " aria-current="page" href="#">home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">aaa</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> bbb</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  ccc
                </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">ssss </a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">vvv</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `margin-bottom: 3px solid #ff7400;` isn't valid. Margins have no color or border-style

Comment: as @j08691 said, `margin-bottom: 3px solid #ff7400;` isn't valid. What you have intended might have been `border-bottom` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> When setting the style for several link states, there are some order
> rules:
>
> a:hover MUST come after a:link and a:visited
>
> a:active MUST come after a:hover

just move your a:visited above your a:hover. For more information on links: [CSS Links - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp)

I think you meant `border` instead of `margin` in your hover.

```
.nav-item a {
  color: #357411;
  font-family: 'Encode Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*visited goes first*/
.nav-item a:visited {
  color: lightseagreen;
}
/*hover after visited*/
.nav-item a:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ff7400; /*border bottom not margin*/
  background: white
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot, but the icons in menu don't change color and they don't have font or green color too. Only links in dropdown menu are green and change into red

Comment: Everything is fine till i delete the "!important" from color in .nav-item

Comment: Ok basically i had to add !important into hover, thanks a lot it was the main issue here :)

Comment: @antekpokrzywa well, that is not exactly the issue. Adding important to overrides every style rule you create and the only way to override an !important is to use another !important. As you can see I removed the !important from the .nav-item a because it was not allowing color to change, but I forgot to mention it on the answer and you should not take it lightly or you will end up adding !important everywhere. This is currently helping you out, but it is not a good practice.

Comment: @antekpokrzywa if you want the list decorations (the dots at the left -that is what I understand you meant by "icons") then you don't need to add an !important, but add a style rule for that class as: .nav-item:hover { /*something*/}

Answer (score 0):

Replace `margin-bottom` with `border-bottom` in `.nav-item a:hover` class.

```css
.nav-item a {
  color: #357411 !important;
  font-family: 'Encode Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ff7400;
  background: white
}

.nav-item a:visited {
  color: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
    <a class="nav-link " aria-current="page" href="#">home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">aaa</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> bbb</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  ccc
                </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">ssss </a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">vvv</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

Change to this:

```
.nav-item a:hover {
    margin-bottom: 3px solid #ff7400;
    background-color: white;
}
```

The background property is wrong, you should use background color.

Comment: still not working, text has green color all the time :/

Comment: Your margin values are invalid and background: white is fine.